# How do I force a full postback from codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, postback

I'd like to programmatically force a full page postback to occur after an event is fired by one of the child controls.  I can't add any triggers to make this work so it will have to be done via code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, don't understand.  By the time an event in codebehind is running, a postback has already happened.

Comment: the control has a timer which then runs a process to see if a scheduled task is complete.  Once complete I want the main window to reload certain contents which are not in update panels and as such the must be a full postback.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a client side event then setup OnClientClick to call what is returned by the following after your other client side functionality:

```
Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(control, "")
```

(It will be something like __dopostback)